# Webapp JSP vs Tag files and resource declaration

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, web-applications, tags

I am learning to write my first web application. I have a jsp file which used .tag files. Both the .jsp and .tag files use jquery functions. In this case should jquery resource be specified in both the files or can i specify it in JSP alone and tag file can use it ?

Since im importing the tag file into a jsp, I assumed the resulting html would be a single file so no need to link the jquery resource in multiple places? Am i correct here?

Something like this:

```
common/dummy.tag
*******************

.
.
.
$("#blah").show();
.
.


Sample.jsp
***********

.
.
.
<common:dummy/>
.
.
.
$("#somethingelse").hinde();
.
.
.
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If i link the jquery in my tag as well is there any issue? Since its possible my tag could be reused some where else which doesnt use jquery byitself.

Comment: You question is not entirely clear. If you mean the jQuery javascript files - yes, you only need to include those in the `head` of your `JSP`.

Comment: I have updated the question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its enough to specify in the JSP ( or tag not required in both ). Had issues when there were multiple location where jquery was linked. Not sure why it would be an issue but remove the duplicate links fixed all the issues.

But anyway would like to know how to handle cases like this where i have JSPs and Tag files. Is it best practice to link resource in both Tag files. as we cant be sure that all the JSPs that use the Tag will need the resource (so expecting the JSP will link the resource isnt the correct thing to do).

Comment: If you look at libraries that use taglibs with external JavaScript resources - like [struts2-jquery](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) - you will see that they usually include a `head` type tag which goes into the HTML `<head>` element. This imports the external resources for use elsewhere.